# GCM for iOS not showing while not debugging

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, google-cloud-messaging

i'm a beginner iOS developer (so.. sorry if I made a stupid mistake). 
I have succeeded implementing GCM, it's running fine when plugged in (run with XCode). But when I unplug my device from my PC, it stopped prompting the banners.
So, when :

- plugged in -> While opening application -> JSON Recieved
- plugged in -> While application on background -> Banners Appear
- unplugged  -> While opening application -> JSON Recieved
- unplugged  -> While application on background -> Nothing

I use these JSON

```
{
"content_available":true,
"to" : "l6rofh8dvAc:AP......BVhhXSYc3thtGklEzJzoZFGRMI7lBk4RhmcW",
"message_id": "1",
"notification" : 
{
    "body" : "helloo!!",
    "title" : "GCM",
    "icon" : "",
    "sound": "default",
    "alert":"default",
    "badge":"12",
    "color": "#03A9F4",
},
"data":
{
    "body":"Hello, How are you?",
    "title":"Test"
}
}
```

is my JSON wrong? or is there something that I missed at the XCode? (i followed the sample from 
[Setting up a GCM Client App on iOS - Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/gcm/GcmExample/AppDelegate.m) (with little modification).

Comment: Your JSON request body looks fine, your app might be terminated after you unplugged your device from computer? You can also check the HTTP response body, see if there is a success response.

Comment: The HTTP POST response is "200 OK". The app might be terminated, but i thought once the device is registered to the GCM server, it should be receiving notification regardless the apps is open or not (if it doesn't, what's the points of push notification?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the priority of the message as `high`. The way you're setting it the priority is set to be low and APNS optimizes battery while sending the message and usually takes hours to deliver the message.

Here is what you need your json to be

```
{
"content_available":true,
"to" : "l6rofh8dvAc:AP......BVhhXSYc3thtGklEzJzoZFGRMI7lBk4RhmcW",
"message_id": "1",
"priority" : "high", # Add this
"notification" : 
{
  ...
},
}
```

You can read more about setting priority here https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

Comment: IT WORKS!! Thank you! :D

Comment: Hello, when you set the `priority` to `high`,  your app will receive push notification even your app is terminated?

Comment: Well it depends if you only have the `content-available` key and no `notification` key in your request you won't. Having a `notification` key would make sure you get the notification even if your app has been terminated.